# Copper vs Stainless Steel - which is more resistant to corrosion?

Tags: corrosion

I keep reading conflicting information on this.

For normal water with a normal ph balance, over time which more resistant to corrosion - copper or stainless steel?

Comment: You should quote these conflicting readings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upvoted the question because it seems so simple, but allows so much discussion about special cases, all of which can and do happen.

First, copper pipe was used for house plumbing because it is so easy to work. Then copper became too expensive, or plastic became cheaper, I'm not sure which. So copper must pass the test of non-corrodability.

Now stainless steel is used in some fixtures for the sink, shower, etc. (Some is only chromium plated.) But stainless steel seems quite durable in "normal" water with a "normal" pH (~7?).

So, it's a tie.

However, if you scratch the stainless steel with a piece of copper tubing, the stainless may well begin to corrode, because the copper will act as a cathode, and by definition, the stainless steel becomes the anode and corrodes away (but slowly). So even if the two metals are almost equal in corrosion resistance (there are many varieties of stainless steel, some of which are exrtemely resistant to corrosion) treating them as equals is not good for corrosion resistance.

And salt water (it's normal...) is especially tough on stainless steel. It would seem that copper would have an advantage there - but no - even cast iron is better! https://www.ecoplumbers.com/2015/05/27/is-saltwater-corrosion-affecting-your-pipes/

So you have to be more specific, establishing the conditions, and maybe even do an experiment, before you can make a blanket statement. Sometimes I wish chemistry was more black/and/white, but all the intricacies sure do make it more interesting.